# Modify Stopword-Removal-Code to remove numbers as well

Tags: python, pandas, stop-words

I have a tokenized text in a df column.
The code to remove the stopwords from it works, but I like to remove punctuation, numbers and special characters as well, without spelling them out.
Like I want to be sure it also deletes numbers that are larger / tokenized as one token.

My current code is:

```
eng_stopwords = stopwords.words('english')
punctuation = ['.', ',', ';', ':', '!' #and so on] 
complete_stopwords = punctuation + eng_stopwords
df['removed'] = df['tokenized_text'].apply(lambda words: [word for word in words if word not in complete_stopwords])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the punctuations from the string module:

```
import string
print(string.punctuation)

'!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'

eng_stopwords = stopwords.words('english')

punctuation = list(string.punctuation) 

complete_stopwords = punctuation + eng_stopwords

df['removed'] = df['tokenized_text'].apply(lambda words: [word for word in words if word not in complete_stopwords])
```

Comment: Thanks, it does work for punctuation!
Do you have any idea for numbers as well? (That might even work with negative numbers)?

Comment: you're welcome @Nip. `string.digits` will give you digits from `'0123456789'`. I am not sure how to use it effectively.